# One directional view pager with one fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am facing one problem **i have one fragment in view pager** which i need to update when user slides from right to left, **slide animation should be there with one fragment**, here are some code that i am trying, the thing is i have view pager inside fragment as well.

Any suggestions code help will be appreciated.

here are some code that i have tried for one directional view pager

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {

    private float initialXValue;
    private SwipeDirection direction;

    public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.direction = SwipeDirection.all;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean IsSwipeAllowed(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.direction == SwipeDirection.all) return true;

        if (direction == SwipeDirection.none)//disable any swipe
            return false;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialXValue = event.getX();
            return true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            try {
                float diffX = event.getX() - initialXValue;
                if (diffX > 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.right) {
                    // swipe from left to right detected
                    return false;
                } else if (diffX < 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.left) {
                    // swipe from right to left detected
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more? i still don't understand, view pager just 1 fragment inside ? and how you swipe with 1 fragment ?

```
public class NoSwipeViewPager extends ViewPager {
    private float initialXValue;
    private SwipeDirection direction;

    public NoSwipeViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.direction = SwipeDirection.all;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.IsSwipeAllowed(event)) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public enum SwipeDirection {
        all, left, right, none;
    }

    private boolean IsSwipeAllowed(MotionEvent event) {
        if (this.direction == SwipeDirection.all) return true;

        if (direction == SwipeDirection.none)
            return false;

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            initialXValue = event.getX();
            return true;
        }

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            try {
                float diffX = event.getX() - initialXValue;
                if (diffX > 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.right) {
                    return false;
                } else if (diffX < 0 && direction == SwipeDirection.left) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public void setAllowedSwipeDirection(SwipeDirection direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
}
```

and when you use:

```
viewPager.setAllowedSwipeDirection(NoSwipeViewPager.SwipeDirection.left);
```

Comment: Sure ,See my main concept is not based on View pager ,The requirement is -1.I have one fragment  user should have functionality to swipe fragment from right to left data will be changed ,so slide animation should be there from right to left with the same fragment

Comment: show me ur code of activity where you use this viewpager

Comment: I think you are not able to get the idea,what i have implemented is another thing ,what i have to implement is a matter of concern ,i hope you got what i have to implement

Comment: uhhhhmmmm. I read your idea again, all you want is just update data in ur fragment when user swipe, right ? if i right, you just can catch swipe action when you have more than 1 fragment inside viewpage.

Comment: yes But i have only one fragment that i need to update ,and i actually dont know the count of a fragment as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try ViewPager's PageTransformer. And here the code example :

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new FadePageTransformer());
```

/**
         * Page Transform for hiding the DPAN in the next card which is partially visible.*/

```
    private class FadePageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

            public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
   // you can do your work when page is transform
            }
        }
```

Hope is will help.